# Firebase SDK for Python: How to initialize App using apiKey?

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, sdk

There is the following code inside a Node.js [project](https://github.com/soonlabs/soonaverse-lib/blob/main/src/index.ts#L22):

```
Soon.app = initializeApp({
  apiKey: "AIzaSyB4fcG8rtNWAiAtSmxmK3q3JLfMvtNCGP4",
  projectId: "soonaverse"
});
```

How can I do the same using the Python SDK? Is this even possible at all? I am looking at this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#python_1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was working with Flask using Firebase. To work with Firebase in Python you will need to install pyerbase package [from here](https://pypi.org/project/Pyrebase/). Copy SDK setup and configuration from Firebase and paste it in config.
I found this [GitHub](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase) repository helpful.

```
from flask import Flask
import pyrebase

app = Flask(__name__)

config = {
  "apiKey": " ",
  "authDomain": " ",
  "projectId": " ",
  "storageBucket": "",
  "messagingSenderId": " ",
  "appId": " ",
  "databaseURL":" ",
  "measurementId": " "
};  

firebase=pyrebase.initialize_app(config)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    return "Hello World"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```